# Entity Framework (DDD), relationship with two foreign keys

Tags: c#, entity-framework, .net-core, domain-driven-design

I'm trying to model EntityTypeConfifuration using Fluent API. Simpler version of tables which I want to reflect in EF are below:

**Exam**

| Id | Data |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | row data |

**ExamTrackedItem**

| Id | TrackedValue | Sha1Hash |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 4 | abc | 0x23123 |

**ExamExamTrackedItem**

| Id | ExamId | TrackedFieldId |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 4 |

Class representation is below:

**Exam**

```
public class Exam : Entity, IAggregateRoot
{
    public int Id { get; private set; }
    private readonly List<ExamExamTrackedItem> _examExamTrackedItems;
}
```

**ExamTrackedItem**

```
public class ExamTrackedItem
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Value { get; set; }
    public byte[] Sha1Hash { get; set; }
}
```

**ExamExamTrackedItem**

```
public class ExamExamTrackedItem
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int ExamId { get; set; } 
    public int ExamTrackedItemId { get; set; }
    public ExamTrackedItem TrackedItem { get; set; }    

}
```

Is there any way to model this relation in order to have new method in Exam class:

```
public void AddTrackedItem(ExamTrackedItem item)
```

Which creates new entry in ExamTrackedItem table and creates proper references in ExamTrackedItem? I was able to model it like this:

```
    internal sealed class ExamEntityTypeConfiguration : IEntityTypeConfiguration<Exam>
    {
        public void Configure(EntityTypeBuilder<Exam> builder)
        {
            builder.ToTable("ExamRoot", "medData");
            builder.HasKey(b => b.Id);
            builder.OwnsMany<ExamMedService>("_examMedServices", x =>
            {
                x.WithOwner().HasForeignKey("ExamId");
                x.ToTable("ExamMedService", "medData");
                x.Property<decimal?>("Price").HasColumnName("Price");
                x.HasKey("Id");
            });
            builder.OwnsMany<ExamExamTrackedItem>("_examExamTrackedItems", x =>
            {
                x.WithOwner().HasForeignKey("ExamId");
                x.ToTable("ExamExamTrackedItem", "medData");
                x.Property<ExamTrackedItemType>("TrackedItemType").HasColumnName("TrackedItemType");
                x.Property<int>("ExamTrackedItemId").HasColumnName("ExamTrackedItemId");
                x.HasKey("Id");

                x.OwnsOne<ExamTrackedItem>("TrackedItem", y =>
                {
                    y.WithOwner().HasPrincipalKey("ExamTrackedItemId");
                    y.ToTable("ExamTrackedItem", "medData");
                    y.Property<string>("Value").HasColumnName("Value");
                    y.Property<byte[]>("Sha1Hash").HasColumnName("Sha1Hash");
                    y.HasKey("Id");
                });
            });
        }
    }
```

But adding new ExamTrackedItem generates SQL which does not fit my needs:

```
SET NOCOUNT ON;
INSERT INTO [medData].[ExamExamTrackedItem] ([ExamId], [ExamTrackedItemId], [TrackedItemType])
OUTPUT INSERTED.[Id]
VALUES (@p0, @p1, @p2);
INSERT INTO [medData].[ExamTrackedItem] ([Id], [Sha1Hash], [Value])
VALUES (@p3, @p4, @p5);
```

I'd rather want to have something like this:

```
INSERT INTO [medData].[ExamTrackedItem] ([Id], [Sha1Hash], [Value])
VALUES (@p3, @p4, @p5);
declare @v_newId in = SCOPE_IDENTITY() 
INSERT INTO [medData].[ExamExamTrackedItem] ([ExamId], [ExamTrackedItemId], [TrackedItemType])
values(@p0, v_newId , @p2)
```

It's probably trivial but I'm learning EF at the moment, so any I'd appreciate any help.

Answer (score 1):

The first question is whether a TrackedItem can be associated to more than one exam? If it can, you want a many-to-many relationship. If not then consider a one-to-many relationship where TrackedItems simply contain an ExamId. While an Owned relationship is possible in a many-to-many scenario, it is a rather odd combination. The point of an owned relationship basically says TrackedItems are to be accessed solely through an Exam, yet many-to-many relationships are associations by nature. You typically use them to express what tracked items are associated to an exam, and what exams are associated to a tracked item. Owned is about ownership, not association.

In terms of a many-to-many relationship, so-long as the joining table really only needs the association FKs you can simplify the entity definitions to reference collections to either end. For instance in Exam you don't need a collection of ExamExamTrackedItem, it can reference a collection of ExamTrackedItem where the joining table is mapped in the background. In this scenario the ExamExamTrackedItem doesn't need a dedicated Id column, it can just use the ExamId + ExamTrackedItemId as a composite PK. This makes it simpler for a more DDD approach is simple since Exam contains its collection of TrackedItem references. For instance:

```
public void AddTrackedItem(ExamTrackedItem item)
{
    ArgumentNullException.ThrowIfNull(item, nameof(item));

    if(!ExamTrackedItems.Any(x => x.ExamTrackedItemId == item.ExamTrackedItemId))
       ExamTrackedItems.Add(item);
}
```

EF will handle the creation of the associated joining table record automatically.

A situation where you would need a joining entity would be cases where there are additional data columns on the joining table beyond the two FKs. For example if you wanted a CreatedAt DateTime recorded for when a TrackedItem was associated to an Exam, or an IsActive flag for a soft-delete. In these cases you would need Exam.ExamExamTrackedItems so a DDD method would work slightly different:

```
public void AddTrackedItem(ExamTrackedItem item)
{
    ArgumentNullException.ThrowIfNull(item, nameof(item));

    if(!ExamExamTrackedItems.Any(x => x.ExamTrackedItemId == item.ExamTrackedItemId))
       ExamExamTrackedItems.Add(new ExamExamTrackedItem(item));
}
```

Here the Exam's AddTrackedItem method would be responsible for creating the joining entity to wrap the new associated tracked item.

The important thing when working with collection navigation properties is that you want to ensure that before adding an item, eager load the collection (Exam.ExamTrackedItems or Exam.ExamExamTrackedItems) or enable lazy loading proxies as a fallback. When working with navigation properties I generally recommend using shadow FKs and avoiding the temptation to try updating entities by FK. Instead, let EF manage the FKs. Setting references via adding to collections will see EF automatically populate the associated FKs if the relationships are set up properly.

Edit: For a many-to-many association between Exam and ExamTrackedItem without a joining entity:

```
internal sealed class ExamEntityTypeConfiguration : IEntityTypeConfiguration<Exam>
{
    public void Configure(EntityTypeBuilder<Exam> builder)
    {
        builder.ToTable("ExamRoot", "medData");
        builder.HasKey(b => b.Id);
        builder.HasMany(b => b.ExamTrackedItems)
            .WithMany(b => b.Exams)
            .UsingEntity("ExamExamTrackedItems",
                l => l.HasOne(typeof(Exam))
                    .WithMany()
                    .HasForeignKey("ExamId")
                    .HasPrincipalKey(nameof(Exam.ExamId)),
                r => r.HasOne(typeof(ExamTrackedItem))
                    .WithMany()
                    .HasForeignKey("ExamTrackedItemId")
                    .HasPrincipalKey(nameof(ExamTrackedItem.ExamTrackedItemId)),
               j => j.HasKey("ExamId", "ExamTrackedItemId"));
        });
    }
}
```

Where Exam contains an `ICollection<ExamTrackedItem> ExamTrackedItems { get; set; }` rather than ExamExamTrackedItems. (And similarly the ExamTrackedItem has a collection of Exams.) This only needs to be configured on one end, so ExamTrackedItemEntityTypeConfiguration does not need a matching configuration setup for the relationship. (It should still work with both sides set up, but can easily lead to odd problems if they don't match up exactly)

Comment: Thank you for your input. Few clarifications:
1. TrackedItem  can be associated with many exams.
2. Yes, having composite key ExamId + TrackedFieldId is very nice idea. 
3. Also yes, having Exam class only with collection of ExamTrackedItem would be best approach.
Having all this in mind, do you have any idea how properly model this relations using Fluent Api?
Best regards!

Comment: Added an edit with an example mapping. All the info on relationship mapping is outlined pretty well on https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/relationships/many-to-many.

Answer (score 0):

Basing on Steve Py answer and this [post](https://github.com/dotnet/efcore/issues/23344) I ended up with

```
            builder.ToTable("ExamRoot", "medData");
            builder.HasKey(b => b.Id);
            builder
                .HasMany(u => u.ExamTrackedItems)
                .WithMany(g => g.Exams)
                .UsingEntity<Appointment.Domain.Exams.ExamExamTrackedItem>(
                    j => j.HasOne(m => m.ExamTrackedItem).WithMany(g => g.ExamExamTrackedItems),
                    j => j.HasOne(m => m.Exam).WithMany(u => u.ExamExamTrackedItems));
```

Hope it helps.